# Java Modulus Operator behaving strangely as an if condition

Tags: java, modulus

Hey guys I have the following if condition...

```
//Add a space if necessary
if (i!=0 && spaceIn>0 && i%spaceIn==0) {
    System.out.println("Converted Letter : " + curLtr + " at position " + i + " Needs a space");
    curLtr = curLtr + " ";
};
```

The 1st 2 conditions are always true with the test input i give it.

Whats happening is the modula condition `i%spaceIn==0` is not reporting as true when it is.

Example when i is 3 and spaceIn is 3 i%spaceIn=0 if condition works.

When i gets to 6 even tho i can see (from system.out further along) that the answer is 0 its not triggering the if condition.

Sometimes it wasn't doing it when i=12 either!

So weird.

Im printing out the answer to i%spaceIn throughout the loop and even tho the answer is 0 every multiple of 3 comes it sometimes wont trigger the if condition.

Same thing if spaceIn is 5. It skips 10. What ever number it is it seems to just skip sometimes for no reason.

What am i missing?

Comment: put some extra code where you defining your i and spacelen

Comment: Are there any other threads changing these values?

Comment: As a general remark, extra parenthesis are always nice in such expression to make it extra clear in which order the different parts are to evaluated. `if ((i!=0) && (spaceIn>0) && (i%spaceIn==0))` is better readable.

Comment: The condition itself seems fine. Also, while Java's `mod` is sometimes unintuitive (because it can return a negative result), it works. The problem is somewhere around, and we need to see more code, ideally a small complete program showing the issue.

Comment: Please try to create a [*"Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example"*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can reproduce your problem on our machines.

Comment: Hey guys thanks a lot for trying to help. I couldn't post more code because it was an assignment and if someone else in the class copied anything searching for a similar problem then plagiarism case might have opened. Sorry I never replied but I figured it out eventually and had a heap of assignments due and just forgot to come back here. Now I cant remember how I fixed it.

Answer (score -2):

Use the following code...
You have terminated the if block... It can cause a problem...

```
if (i!=0 && spaceIn>0 && i%spaceIn==0) {
System.out.println("Converted Letter : " + curLtr + " at position " + i + " Needs a space");
curLtr = curLtr + " "; }
```

I hope it might work for you as it runs fine on my machine....

Comment: How does this answer the question? The `if` condition is exactly the same.

Comment: *"You have terminated the if block... It can cause a problem"* ...  no it can't. This semicolon is an empty statement after the `if`.